# Understanding the difference between pointing knowledge, pointing accuracy and pointing stability?

Tags: low-earth-orbit, terminology, attitude-determination-and-control, equipment, accuracy

In terms of specifications for satellite Attitude Determination And Control System (ADCS) hardware, my understanding is that *pointing knowledge* is for attitude determination, whereas *pointing accuracy* is for attitude control.

When the Original Equipment Manufacturers (OEMs) give the specs, do they take into consideration the orbital disturbances?

If not, is it required to model them?

And does *pointing stability* mean the ability of the ADCS to hold the satellite while pointing (stationkeeping, ext disturbances, etc) or does it mean the minimum step for sweeping per second?

Comment: You should almost always spell out acronyms on first use. I did that for you. The only exception I can think of are NASA and ESA.

Comment: More details would be helpful regard what OEMs, what equipment, and what specs you are asking about. This potentially has the makings for a good question, but as of now it's a bit vague.